# Issue with mocking service in jasmine test cases

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I created a mock of existing service simply by extending it as below

```js
    class mockData extends DataService {
      markCompleted() {
        return ('completed');
      }
    
      onTDC() {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

and made the necessary changes to the beforeEach segment as given below

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [BasicComponent],
          providers: [{ provide: DataService, useValue: mockData }]
        })
```

but when I try and use the mocked services i get an error saying method does not exist

The use case where i tried to use the service is as below

```js
    it('should check if the markCompletion is called from markLessonAsCompleted', () => {
        const markCompletionspy = spyOn<any>(component, 'markCompletion');
        let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(DataService);
        spyOn(service, 'markCompleted').and.returnValue(undefined);
    
        
        component.markAsCompleted();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(markCompletionspy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      });
```

Comment: Try changing the `useValue` to `useClass`.

Comment: @AliF50 thanks man that helped